# I need to show World map with GroundOverlay on map with animation

Tags: android, google-maps, animation, world-map, gmsgroundoverlay

I need to show world map on my application.
I tried to use MapView and set liteMode= true and zoomLevel=1 but its not working as i need. Also groundOverlay not supported in liteMode and i need to show multiple groundOverlay on WorldMap.
can anyone know about it?

Please refere below link i need to show full world map like this.

https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b0/World_location_map_%28equirectangular_180%29.svg

Below code i done :

```
    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
                        android:id="@id/mapView"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/dp_180"
                        map:liteMode="true"
                        map:cameraZoom="1"
                        map:mapType="normal"
                        />
```

In my Java Class

```
 @Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    if (googleMap != null) {
        this.googleMap = googleMap;
        this.googleMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(false);
        this.googleMap.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(false);
        this.googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        this.googleMap.setMapStyle(MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(getContext(), R.raw.style_json));

        this.googleMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(false);
        this.googleMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(false);
        this.googleMap.getUiSettings().setScrollGesturesEnabled(false);
}
```

In this is added zoomLevel=1 but in google map its not showing world map as like above image link i shared.

Comment: Have you checked [this?](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/styling)

Comment: Yes @Piyush i checked that but i don't have google map style issue.

Comment: If you have issue with GroundOverLay then show some snippet code.

Comment: i don't have issue with groundOverlay .I have issue  with Google Map zooming. I need to show world map like link i uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

```
CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().
                    target(YourLocationPoint).
                    tilt(60).
                    zoom(15).
                    bearing(0).
                    build();

myMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
```

You can use tilt and bearing for achieving same [Doc](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/views)

Comment: I need to show world map and need to add multiple markers on it not for particular one marker. Please refer attached link.I need to show map like this

Answer (score 0):

Set style for Google map , in **onMapReady**  of your activity.

```
googleMap.setMapStyle(MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(getActivity(), R.raw.customized_map_style));
```

you need to download the style. please go through below link
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/styling

update the styles as you wish.

Comment: i don't need to set style on map..Please read my question again. This is not what i am asking.

Comment: by styling you can achieve it.. you can hide the roads and can give any colors.